# Building Blazor Electron App for Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: electron, blazor, arm64, ubuntu-20.04, raspberry-pi4

I have been able to create a blazor electron demo application following: https://github.com/jimbuck/blazor-electron-demo but unfortunately I'm having trouble building for arm64 so that I can put the application on my pi. I've only been able to build x64 linux executables using the "dotnet electronize build /target linux" command. What can I use to build/publish the application for linux arm64?

Comment: I don't know anything what electronize does. On the other hand you use ```dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-arm``` to create linux-arm builds.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish